# What does $$i do in this makefile loop?

Tags: makefile

I have a simple loop in my makefile:

```
@ for i in $(APPDIRS) ; do \
    $(MAKE) -C $$i real_clean ; \
    done
```

I know $$ means [process id](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#PROCCID) of the script itself. What does the 'i' do? Am I iterating through the process id with the for loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$` is used both as the variable identifier for `make` and for the shell. So if you want the *shell* to expand a variable, rather than having the makefile do it, you need to escape the `$` by using `$$`.

As a quick example, let's assume `APPDIRS=a b c d e f` and `MAKE=make` (and `i` unset in the makefile). Then your shell sees:

```
for i in a b c d e f ; do
    make -C $i real_clean;
done
```

With a `$` in place of the `$$`, it would see:

```
for i in a b c d e f ; do
    make -C  real_lean;
done
```

Which is *definitely* not what you want.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. I didn't realize that $ was used as an escape character.